# Что лучше при поиске чисел Фибоначчи - рекурсия или простое сложение?

Tags: java, алгоритм, числа-фибоначчи, задание-на-собеседовании

1. Почему поиск чисел Фибоначчи решается с помощью рекурсии? В интернете много примеров с рекурсией - чем простое сложение не нравится?
2. С рекурсией решается быстрее, если искать до 21 числа, а вот все что больше уже намного быстрее решается простым сложением. Почему с рекурсией быстрее, ведь это получается больше почти 100 раз вызов самого себя?

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       long l = System.nanoTime();
       long findFib = 16;
       System.out.println("not recursion = " + fib(findFib));
       l = System.nanoTime() - l;
       System.out.println("time = " + l);
       l = System.nanoTime();
       System.out.println("recursion =    " + recFib(findFib));
       l = System.nanoTime() - l;
       System.out.println("time = " + l);
   }

   private static long fib(long i) {
      long curr = 1;
      long previous = 0;
      for (long j = 0; j < i - 1; j++) {
          long temp = curr;
          curr += previous;
          previous = temp;
      }
      return curr;
   }

   private static long recFib(long i) {
       if (i < 2) {
           return i;
       }
       return recFib(i - 1) + recFib(i - 2);
   }
   ```

Comment: Обычно рекурсия с числами Фибоначчи приводится как пример "так делать нельзя!". Вы внимательно читали?

Comment: @harry во всех примерах в интернете пишут так?), другой вопрос почему в маленьких случаях это быстрее

Comment: @regent да, можно оптимизировать, добавив еще одну проверку, но для -1 и -2 вернется 0. добавил теперь рекурсия быстрее до 18 числа

Comment: @JMas это не столько оптимизация, сколько часть алгоритма: два элемента (обычно с индексами 0 и 1) зафиксированы, а остальные рассчитываются на их основе.

Comment: Рекурсия при получении чисел Фибоначчи используется исключительно в главе "Рекурсия для начинающих". Т.е. не для получения чисел, а для объяснения, что есть рекурсия. *Почему с рекурсией быстрее* Потому что так написана нерекурсивная функция. Сделал бы типа `fib[0]=0; fib[1]=1; for(i=2;i<N;i++){fib[i%2]=fib[0]+fib[1];}; return fib[N%2];` - было бы быстрее...

Comment: Потому что точно замерить малые случаи не получится :) - тут очень играют роль накладные расходы.

Comment: @harry накладные расходы для обоих всех одинаковые и разница большая выходит при больших числах

Comment: https://ideone.com/rfjifS - вот, смотрите сами и не говорите ерунды...

Comment: Да, вы правы, изменил код чтобы два раза вызывал или рекурсивный или не рекурсивный, действительно разница очень большая, бывает даже раз в 20. Почему так? Как изменять правильно

Comment: @Harry Но тот же ideone для Java выдает именно так как пишет ТС https://ideone.com/CwI5hq  рекурсия раза в 2 быстрее. Подозреваю, что это какие то особенности работы с переменными именно в java.

Comment: @harry Почему такая разница в числах, даже если вызываю ту же самую функцию?

Comment: Да потому что вы меряете время вывода на экран или куда оно там выводит, а не время счета...

Comment: @harry даже если я не вывожу у меня разница в десять раз,
        long time1 = System.nanoTime();
        int findFib = 22;
        fib(findFib);
        time1 = System.nanoTime() - time1;
        long time2 = System.nanoTime();
        fib(findFib);
        time2 = System.nanoTime() - time2;
        out.println("time1 = " + time1);
        out.println("time2 = " + time2);

time1 = 6952
time2 = 994

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ваши два вопроса построены одинаково - спрашивается, почему о неверных вещах. Потому что это на самом деле не так.

1. В дидактических целях, чтобы показать, *что* такое рекурсия. Чтобы показать, что неразумное применение рекурсии ведет к неработоспособной программе.
2. С рекурсией **не** быстрее никогда - по крайней мере для чисел Фибоначчи и без мемоизации.

Сравнение вот таких функций

```
long long fibR(unsigned int N)
{
    if (N < 2) return 1;
    return fibR(N-1) + fibR(N-2);
}

long long fibI(unsigned int N)
{
    if (N < 2) return 1;
    long long f0 = 1, f1 = 1;
    for(unsigned int i = 2; i <= N; ++i)
    {
        long long f = f0 + f1;
        f0 = f1;
        f1 = f;
    }
    return f1;
}
```

на моей машине дает (ссылка на полный код ниже; простите, я на C++ работаю, но не думаю, что на Java что-то изменится :))

```
N(i) =   3         3         0 mks
N(r) =   3         3         1 mks
N(i) =   6        13         0 mks
N(r) =   6        13         5 mks
N(i) =   9        55         0 mks
N(r) =   9        55        22 mks
N(i) =  12       233         0 mks
N(r) =  12       233        95 mks
N(i) =  15       987         0 mks
N(r) =  15       987       406 mks
N(i) =  18      4181         0 mks
N(r) =  18      4181      1718 mks
N(i) =  21     17711         0 mks
N(r) =  21     17711      7301 mks
N(i) =  24     75025         0 mks
N(r) =  24     75025     24896 mks
N(i) =  27    317811         0 mks
N(r) =  27    317811     86819 mks
N(i) =  30   1346269         0 mks
N(r) =  30   1346269    370024 mks
N(i) =  33   5702887         0 mks
N(r) =  33   5702887   1568399 mks
```

Примерно тот же результат получается и тут: https://ideone.com/rfjifS

Comment: Подпишите плиз, что у вас в таблице показано, какие столбцы?

Comment: По результатам я так понял что нерекурсивный вариант выполняет за 0 микросекунд любое число. Почему так быстро?

Comment: @JMas Так это C, программа выполняется прямо на процессоре. А складывает и перемещает в кеше пару значений процессор оооочень быстро.

Comment: @mike тогда другой вопрос. почему на С так долго рекурсия идет? так же я не понял тему про С рекурсией не быстрее никогда, вы имели ввиду что с рекурсией всегда долго, почему?

Comment: @JMas Думаю в случае с циклом, так как переменных всего 4 (со счетчиком цикла), все операции вообще проходят в регистрах, даже работы с памятью нет (кроме возврата результата). А в случае рекурсии приходится значения сохранять в стеке, делать вызов процедуры. потом еще один if (не известно как предсказатель переходов его отрабатывает и не сбрасывает ли конвеер), плюс в функциях куча лишней работы по подготовке и выходу из функции

Comment: @JMas потому что происходит сильно много вызовов функции (самой себя), а как известно на вызов функции тратится процессорное время, причем не мало. + при определенном количестве чисел вы вообще можете получить stackoverflow если конечно у вас не хвостовая рекурсия.

Comment: "С рекурсией не быстрее никогда" Если язык умеет хвостовую рекурсию, то с рекурсией будет то же самое, что и с циклом.

Comment: @Suvitruf Не обрывайте цитату - *С рекурсией не быстрее никогда - по крайней мере для чисел Фибоначчи и без мемоизации*.

Comment: С рекурсией Фибоначчи - просто издевательство, потому что выполняется масса **повторных** вызовов, в результате получаем, грубо говоря, O(2^N)...

Comment: @Harry у вас текст просто построен так, будто вам ненавистны рекурсии и невнимательный человек подумает, что рекурсии - это плохо.